# 16.04 - Wifi "device not ready" after installing driver for Realtek 8723

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

My laptop is HP 14qcs0009tu with Realtek 8723 WiFi. I have dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.6 and after some searching, I found a driver and was able to run these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms git build-essential
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo cp -r rtlwifi_new/firmware/rtlwifi/ /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
```

The result was an added 'Enable Wi-fi' ticked in the connections menu but a greyed out "device not ready" and the Wi-fi is still not working.

I have looked at many similar questions and run all those steps but to no avail, such as:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo service wicd stop
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
echo "blacklist hp_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Please help me get WiFi working on Ubuntu 16.04.

Adding output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de, wl
```

Output of rfkill list:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of dmesg | grep 8723:

```
[   25.614612] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[   25.614614] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[   25.763485] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin failed with error -2
[   25.763490] Bluetooth: Necessary config file rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin not found
[   25.763495] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[   25.763512] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin failed with error -2
[   25.763514] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[   25.839608] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[   25.839610] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[   25.839621] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin failed with error -2
[   25.839623] Bluetooth: Necessary config file rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin not found
[   25.839626] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[   25.839632] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin failed with error -2
[   25.839633] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[   26.524345] rtl8723de: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin
[   26.558031] rtl8723de 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin failed with error -2
[   26.855209] rtl8723de 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Added it. @Pilot6

Comment: All looks well. The driver is installed. Wifi should work.

Comment: It says "device not ready", could the driver be bad?

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep 8723`

Comment: Added it. @Pilot6

Comment: You need firmware `rtl8723defw.bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system doesn't have firmware `rtl8723defw.bin`.

You can get it from `linux-firmware` git. Run

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
```

Then reboot.

If the signal is weak, you can change antenna selection in the driver.

Run

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf <<< "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

Comment: This got wifi running for me. I'm still getting a poor signal on ubuntu compared to windows, do you think it could be caused due to a poor driver? I'm marking this as accepted answer nonetheless.

Comment: I am updating the answer to fix weak signal.